Which bitcoin mining pools can be used with a Bitaxe miner?
I recently acquired a Bitaxe bitcoin miner.
Which mining pools can I configure it to be used with?
It's default pool was configured to mine to https://web.public-pool.io, but when I search on that site for the bitcoin address that I specified for my payout address, no statistics of any sort appear.  I'm thinking the pool is broken somehow.  I want to try configuring the miner to use a different pool, but I don't know where to look for others.

On the bitaxe configuration, you should be using public-pool.io. Web.public-pool.io is the web page that allows you to see your unit's activity. I have four BitAxe's setup and they show up just fine, with the proper configuration.
